# The stat preceding -l _ wasn't an lstat

Tags: perl

Look at two examples:

```perl
$ perl -e ' print -e "registrar" && -d _ ? "YES" : "NO" '
YES

$ perl -e ' print -e "registrar" && -l _ ? "YES" : "NO" '
The stat preceding -l _ wasn't an lstat at -e line 1.
```

`-d` and `-l` are both file test operators. Why second does not work? The stat preceding -l _ is same as for -d _.

Comment: I guess my Perl knowledge is more out-of-date than I thought. What is `print -e` supposed to do, and what does `_` refer to in the absence of a preceding file test? I'm more surprised that `-d _` is true than I am that `-l _` fails.

Comment: @chepner `-e` is a file test for existence. `print` is a way to display the outcome of the test `-e && -d ? "Yes": "No"`. `_` is shorthand for "use the most recently used file again".

Comment: Oh, of course :facepalm:. It's been a while; I picturing `&&` as joining the commands `print -e "registrar"` with `-d ? "YES" : "NO"`, rather than treating `-e "registrar" && -d _ ? "YES" : "NO"` as the expression to be printed.

Comment: And once again the suggestion to use `diagnostics` is deleted. I really don't get why people who have the ability to delete other people's comments love abusing the power. Maybe I should include it in my answer...

Comment: @Shawn: I think I will write to administrators, so they revoke this power from that person.

Comment: @Shawn I've tried raising the issue on meta, but it turns out people are not interested in opinions that are different from the "norm" when it comes to comments. Comments are a bad thing, and temporary. Eugen: You'll want to raise the issue on meta.stackoverflow.com, I believe. But be warned that people there don't like dissenting opinions.

Comment: Also, @EugenKonkov, did I call it or what? Our comments were deleted, because they referred to moderation. If a comment A is deleted, any comment B asking about that comment being deleted is subject to deletion. Any comment commenting on comment B is deleted.

Comment: @TLP I often meet useful comments with many upvotes 50+. Sometimes comments do not answer the question, but have relation to topic, and are more useful then original answer. The comment with proposition to use `-Mdiagnostics` helped me though. If I knew that option, probably, I did not ask this question at all. Also this is strange to see bulk of comments about nothing here, but useful comments be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the file tests use `stat`, which follows symlinks; `-l` uses `lstat` because it makes no sense to follow one if you want to test if it itself is a symbolic link. Hence the error.

The [`diagnostics` pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics) can be used to give a more verbose explanation of errors and warnings, including this one:

```bash
$  perl -Mdiagnostics -E 'say -e "registrar" && -l _ ? "YES" : "NO" '
The stat preceding -l _ wasn't an lstat at -e line 1 (#1)
    (F) It makes no sense to test the current stat buffer for symbolic
    linkhood if the last stat that wrote to the stat buffer already went
    past the symlink to get to the real file.  Use an actual filename
    instead.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        The stat preceding -l _ wasn't an lstat at -e line 1.
```

If using perl 5.10 or newer, file tests can be directly chained without needing to be `&&`ed together. Doing this with `-e` and `-l` works since perl is smart enough to pick the appropriate stat function:

```bash
$ mkdir registrar
$ perl -E ' say -e -d "registrar" ? "YES" : "NO" '
YES
$ perl -E ' say -e -l "registrar" ? "YES" : "NO" '
NO
```

---

> I actually need **exists** and **not link**. Is there short hand for that?

That shorthand notation only works for simple and-ing all the tests together, but you can call `lstat` directly to see if a file exists:

```bash
$ ln -s registrar registrar-link
$ perl -E 'say lstat "registrar" && ! -l _ ? "YES" : "NO" '
YES
$ perl -E 'say lstat "registrar-link" && ! -l _ ? "YES" : "NO" '
NO
$ perl -E 'say lstat "no-such-file" && ! -l _ ? "YES" : "NO" '
NO
```

And in a script as opposed to a one-liner, I'd use [`File::stat`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::stat) instead of the underscore notation.

Comment: I used `&&` because I actually need **exists** and **not link**. Is there short hand for that? `-e $x && !-l $x`

Comment: @EugenKonkov You can directly call `lstat` instead of using `-e`: `perl -E 'say lstat "registrar" && ! -l _ ? "YES" : "NO" '`

Comment: Putting the `-l` test first might work too.